# unable to click modal popup using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

I Have an application developed using Electron+Chromium when browser launched without any URL there will be a popup.

This is a modal popup and using selenium I'm unable to handle this popup.

[image]

HTML Code for Modal popup

```
 <div class="mt-4">
        <button id="btnCancel" class="btn btn-secondary btn-danger btn-radius" data-i18n="checkSecurityPage.quit">Quit</button>
        <button id="btnNext" class="btn btn-primary btn-radius" data-size="l" data-style="slide-left" data-i18n="checkSecurityPage.next">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Please give any suggestions for it.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add HTML code for the modal mentioned?

Comment: Added the HTML Code

Comment: You will probably need something as browser.switchTo() because modals are not a part of the same window.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using below XPath

`//*[@id="btnCancel"]` to quit

`//*[@id="btnNext"]` to proceeding to next